# Homogeneous Arrays

Tags: matrices, computer-science

I have this problem for homework and was wondering if anyone could help me out with it:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a cell needs  =  520-10 / 16*16 = 2 bits

a)

7th row 14th column , cell number = 6*15 + 14 = 104

address = 10 + 104*2 = 218

b)

7th column 14th row = 13*15 + 7 = 202

address = 10+202*2 = 414